# Align Buttons with same width and height - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image: I'm trying to do something like this:]

I'm using linear layout, so I use the weight atribute, and the width works perfecly, but the height is different, because every screen is different, this is what is happening

[image]

Comment: put your code what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set height and with according to screen pixels and you can get height and width pixels using DisplayMetrics class